# Deploy ASP.NET with full .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment, asp.net-core

I'm wonderinf if it possible to deploy my asp.net core application if I also use some library from .NET 4.5.2.

To describe my problem, in my app I use SyndicationFeed which comes from full .NET
and in my project.json in "framework" section I have:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ServiceModel": ""
      },
      "dependencies": {
      }
    },
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
```

In the other sections I use ASP.CORE packages like:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Hangfire.AspNetCore": "1.6.8",
```

and more.

So the question is is it possible to deploy to the IIS. Should I deploy to server with run with ASP.CORE or full .NET.

Comment: Can't you manually port syndicate feed? What we did is use dotPeek to decompile code from non dotnet core packages and just make em dotnet complient. Mostly took only 1/2 hours per package. (Eg I did this for cloudinary)

Answer (score 1):

In short: yes, it's possible. But full .NET Framework required (on server).

Long story:

Having two `frameworks` in `projects.json` effectively creates two different apps (one for `net462`, other for `netcoreapp1.1`) during compilation/publishing. This is two different applications, compiled for different frameworks from same source code.

To run first (for net462) you need machine with .NET Framework installed. For other (for netcoreapp) you need .NET Core installed. You can't "swap" (run `net462`-build app on `.NET Core` and vice versa).

But looking at your `project.json` I can't believe your app compiles successfully. You need `System.ServiceModel` for your app to work. But it's available only for net462. This means that during compilation first app (for net462) compiles successfully, while second (net netcoreapp) should fail (class not found, namespace not found, etc).

Run `dotnet build` or `dotnet publish` from command line in project/solution folder. See any errors?

So, you can't create/build/run under `.NET Core` while you need packages/classes not available for .NET Core.

Possible solutions:

- Replace package for netcore-compatible (if any exist, I don't know), or re-build (port) existing to be compatible (as Joel says);
- Completely remove this package (implement required code yourself);
- Do not target `netcoreapp1.1`;
- Add conditional compilation (`#if`) where you use this package, so you will use if only in `net462`-version of your app. Otherwise (`#else`) add NotImplementedException, null result or something other (it depends) - effectively you will have two **different** apps after compilation: full-functional for `net462` and restricted-functional for `netcoreapp`.